# Post Count for Categories, however not to calculate a total

Tags: categories, widgets

Normally this is how the category widget works.

```
Fruits (15)
- Apples (7)
- Oranges (3)
- Grapes (5)
```

Apples, Oranges and Grapes contains posts, however nothing in Fruits.

Lets assume that Fruits has 10 posts.

It would look like this.

```
Fruits (25)
- Apples (7)
- Oranges (3)
- Grapes (5)
```

However, I would like it to look like this:

```
Fruits (10)
- Apples (7)
- Oranges (3)
- Grapes (5)
```

The main category Fruits does NOT count up all the sub-category posts, rather its own posts.